# Unicode arabic string to user it

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, decode

i have a variable holding a value like `x='مصطفى'` and i want to convert it to the form of `u'مصطفى'`  to user it again in some functions .. when i try to do `u''+x` it alawys give me an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any help ?

Comment: what is the source for the `x` bytestring?  (do you read it from a file? receive from a network?) You should convert it to Unicode as soon as you get it in your program (using an appropriate character encoding that depends on where the value comes from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks I solved it :)

the solution will be to do so

```
u''.encode('utf-8')+x
```

Comment: No, this is bad. Read the Unicode how-to: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 3):

You have to know what encoding those bytes are in, and them `.decode(encoding)` them to get a Unicode string.  If you received them from some API, `utf8` is a good guess.  If you read the bytes from a file typed in Windows Notepad, it is more likely some Arabic(?) code page.

```
PythonWin 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.
>>> x='مصطفى' # "Just bytes" in whatever encoding my console uses
>>> x         # Looks like UTF-8.
'\xd9\x85\xd8\xb5\xd8\xb7\xd9\x81\xd9\x89'
>>> x.decode('utf8')  # Success
u'\u0645\u0635\u0637\u0641\u0649'
>>> print(x.decode('utf8'))
مصطفى
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two things.

First the meaning of `x='مصطفى'` is ill-defined, and changes if you save your source file in another encoding. On the other hand `x=u'مصطفى'.encode('utf-8')` unambiguously means “the bytes you get when you encode that text with UTF-8”.

Second, either use bytes `'abc'` or `b'abc'` or unicode `u'abc'`, but **don't mix them**. Mixing them in python 2.x produces results which are dependent on where you execute that code. In python 3.x it raises an error (for good reasons).

So given a byte string `x`, either:

```
# bytes
'' + x
```

or:

```
# unicode, so decode the byte string
u'' + x.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are tow libraries in python called `python-bidi` and `arabic_reshaper` using them you can Write arabic text without any problems or hidden letters or separate letters etc.

Download them by typing in terminal: `pip install python-bidi, arabic_reshaper`

Example:

```
import bidi.algorithm, arabic_reshaper

# To get arabic outputs in terminal or kivy or even pyGame etc.
reshaper = arabic_reshaper.reshape("أهلا وسهلا بكم")
bidi_text = bidi.algorithm.get_display(reshaper)
# "bidi_text" above makes python read from right to left like arabic language
print(bidi_text)

# Result in terminal:
>>>أهلا وسهلا بكم 

# To append arabic text in a text file:
File = open('av.txt', 'w',encoding='utf-8')
File.write(reshaper)
```