# Json and non-English languages

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and trying hard to learn it.

I was trying to save tweets by using Tweepy and because my query is in "**Arabic**" the results seems to be strange like this:

```
"created_at": "Mon Jun 12 15:12:50 +0000 2017", "id": 874283356158033920, "id_str": "874283356158033920", "text": "\\u0637\\u0627\\u0644\\u0628\\u0629 \\u062c\\u0633\\u0645\\u0647\\u0627 \\u062c\\u0628\\u0627\\u0631 \\u062a\\u062a\\u062e\\u062f \\u0645\\u0646 \\u0627\\u0644\\u0634\\u0627\\u0631\\u0639 \\u0648 \\u062a\\u062a\\u0646\\u0627\\u0643..\\n\\n\\u0633\\u0643\\u0633_\\u0627\\u062c\\u0646\\u0628\\u064a\\n\\u0645\\u0642\\u0627\\u0637\\u0639_\\u0633\\u0643\\u0633\\nbabes\\n2236 ", "truncated": false, "entities"
```

I tried many times and saw many similar questions here but couldn't find the answer. Does Json support the Arabic language?

here is my code:

```
import tweepy
import json
from pprint import pprint
import time
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("", "")
auth.set_access_token("", "")
api = tweepy.API(auth)
max_tweets=100
query='الشارع'
searched_tweets = [status._json for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,  q=query).items(max_tweets)]
json_strings = [json.dumps(json_obj) for json_obj in searched_tweets]  
print(json_strings)
```

I'm using Python3

Comment: The only problem here is that you're printing a list of serialized JSON instead of serializing a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode arabic string to user it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555473/unicode-arabic-string-to-user-it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196321/how-do-i-input-arabic-text-into-my-python-code

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack ahh ok, thanks - will delete comments

Comment: I'm using Python3

Comment: Although those unicode-escape sequences are annoying when you want to see the actual text, they have the advantage of being very robust. So if your JSON gets processed on a system that doesn't have good UTF-8 support, or uses a different Unicode encoding (the JSON default _is_ UTF-8, but  UTF-16 or UTF-32 are also permitted) your data won't get mangled.

Comment: Thank you PM for your explanation. I'm new here and these rules are absent from my mind. I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that by default `json.dumps()` encodes any non ASCII characters using escaped Unicode notation, which optional in the JSON specification. By passing `ensure_ascii=False` to `dumps()`, this will disable this feature.

The second problem you'll have once you fixed the main problem, is you'll try to print list. Python will the print a **representation** of the list, including representations of the data inside it. This means that the data includes literals and a safe way to print data.

For strings, this means that the object is printed with quotes and any non-ascii characters are printed as Unicode escape sequences.

Try:

```
json_strings = [json.dumps(json_obj, ensure_ascii=False) for json_obj in searched_tweets]  
for tweet in json_strings:
    print(tweet)
```

Comment: I copied your code in my code, and the same results appears.

Comment: ok, see addition of `ensure_ascii=false` in `dumps`. I'll explain if it works

Comment: it said:  name 'false' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, `false` should be `False`

Comment: Explanation given

Comment: Thank goodness that the OP is using Python 3. This sort of thing can be painful in Python 2. :)

Comment: Appreciate your effort Alastair,,