# Twitter Search Program

Tags: python

I'm using [this program](https://github.com/agalea91/twitter_search/blob/master/twitter_search.py), and all the tweets that I'm getting are like this"because it is in Arabic Language":

```
"text": "\\u0637\\u0627\\u0644\\u0628\\u0629 \\u062c\\u0633\\u0645\\u0647\\u0627 \\u062c\\u0628\\u0627\\u0631 \\u062a\\u062a\\u062e\\u062f \\u0645\\u0646 \\u0627\\u0644\\u0634\\u0627\\u0631\\u0639 \\u0648 \\u062a\\u062a\\u0646\\u0627\\u0643..\\n\\n\\u0633\\u0643\\u0633_\\u0627\\u062c\\u0646\\u0628\\u064a\\n\\u0645
```

I had a question about it and got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503253/json-and-non-english-languages/44503363#44503363)

the question is : Where I can use `ensure_ascii=False` in the program so it can read the Arabic tweet correctly? I don't know in which place I need to copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify `twitter_search.py`

Replace all

```
json.dump(<something>,fd)
```

For

```
json.dump(<something>,fd,ensure_ascii=False)
```

You'll also need to replace all `<file_descriptor>` for utf-8 ones

```
import codecs
...
...
fd = codecs.open("/tmp/lol", "w", "utf-8")
```

If you're processing the results with python another approach would be to unescape the ascii string.

```
s='\\u0637\\u0627\\u0644\\u0628\\u0629...'
print s.encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: I did what you said but with no result, IDK why

Comment: the result is: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 12-16: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I couldn't apply your code, I'm new to Python. could you please write it for me if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks I did it. Your code worked great,, thank you for your help